# Convert a single list item of key value pair to an dictionary in python

Tags: list, key-value

I have function that returns just one list of key-value pair.  How can I convert this to an actual key value or an object type so I can get each attribute from the list. For example I would like to be able to just get the time or price or any other property and not the whole list as one item.

`{'time': 1512858529643, 'price': '0.00524096', 'origQty': '530.00000000'`

I know it doesn't look like a list but it actually is! The function that I am calling returns this as a list.  I am simply storing it to a variable and nothign else.

`open_order=client.get_open_orders(symbol="BNBETH",recvWindow=1234567)`

If you still have doubts.  When I try to print a dictionary item like this `print(open_order['time'])`

I get the following error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\python-binance-master\main.py", line 63, in <module>
    print(open_order['time'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Also If I show type it shows as list.

```
print(type(open_order))
```

So, I was able to come up with a solution, sort of... by converting the list to string and splitting at the "," character.   Now I have list of items that I can actually print by selecting one `print(split_order_items[5])` There has to be a better solution.

`open_order=client.get_open_orders(symbol="BNBETH",recvWindow=1234567)
    y=''.join(str(e)for e in open_order)
    split_order_items =([x.strip() for x in y.split(',')])
    print(split_order_items[5])`

I was able to create a multiple list items using the above code.  I just can't seem to convert it to dictionary object!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of usage code that you would like to see? You want to change a list of dictionaries into list of ...? Or you mean something like convert your list into NamedTuple?

Comment: Trying what you have shared gives me `>>> print(type(a)) # <class 'dict'>`

Comment: The shown "list" is definitely a `dict`

Comment: I i guess if you set this to a variable  python think it's dict.  But the function that I am calling returns this as a list.  ( I didn't write this function it's an API that I am using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have posted is a `dict`, not a list. You can do something like this:

```
data = {'time': 1512858529643, 'price': '0.00524096', 'orderId': 7848174, 'origQty': '530.00000000'}
print(data['time']) # this gets just the time and prints it
print(data['price']) # this gets just the price and prints it
```

I strongly suggest reading up on the Python `dict`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: That's the thing!  I thought it was a list but when I try to do following `open_order=client.get_open_orders(symbol="BNBETH",recvWindow=1234567)
    print(open_order['time'])` i got the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\python-binance-master\main.py", line 63, in <module>
    print(open_order['time'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Can you try replacing `print(open_order['time'])` with `print(str(open_order))` and post the output? Just so I can get a better picture of what `open_order` actually is

Comment: `[{'orderId': 7848174, 'price': '0.00524096', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'symbol': 'BNBETH''}]`

Comment: This is a `list` of `dict` objects, which happens to only contain a single `dict` object. If you are guaranteed it will *always* have only a single `dict` object, you can do something like this:

`print(open_order[0]['time'])` (access the first element of `open_order`)

If it can have multiple items, you can iterate over them using a for-loop and then print the `element['time']` for each element in your list